# anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

Estoy probando *spark* en *maven* pero me da este problema quiero que me muestre el puerto pero el `runable` me muestra este error

> "anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments"

**Código**

```
public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spark.get(new Route("/"){
        @Override
        public Object handle(Request rqst, Response rspns) throws Exception 
      {
            return "Hello World From Spark";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que recibes se refiere que estas instando un objeto de una clase anónima basado en una interfaz y tratas de pasar un argumento como si tuviera un constructor aceptando el argumento.

Si quieres que una clase anónima recibe un argumento, tienes que extender una clase abstracta que provee este constructor para construirla.

Un `interface` en java no permite declarar constructores.